# Excel: Merge financial data with different discrete dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Suppose I have two sets of data, each is two columns (Date and amount). The thing is the dates do NOT lie on the same exact days, and in the end, I want a single set (Date column and amount column), how do I do that in excel?
For example:

| Date | Amount 1 |  | Date | Amount 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-01-2020 | 100 |  | 15-01-2020 | 150 |
| 13-01-2020 | 130 |  | 19-01-2020 | 100 |
| 20-01-2020 | 200 |  | 25-01-2020 | 250 |

and I need

| Date | Amount 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 10-01-2020 | 100+0 |
| 13-01-2020 | 130+0 |
| 15-01-2020 | 130+150 |
| 19-01-2020 | 130+100 |
| 20-01-2020 | 200+100 |
| 25-01-2020 | 200+250 |

Comment: What are your rules for grouping the results?

Comment: For each event (date on either sets) add current value in both sets. The values "amount" are the current value as it changes with time.
I hope I am clear.

Comment: Not at all clear to me. But maybe someone else will be able to understand.  What do these two tables represent?

Comment: your result column, do you want both numbers in there, or just a sum? Would a pivot table work for you?

Comment: @gns100 I need the sum and Pivot is fine. Thanks in advance.